# Перевод термина "nondecreasing"

Tags: переводы

Есть ли способ элегантно перевести термин nondecreasing?

"Неубывание" звучит достаточно плоско.

Comment: Нормально звучит. Точно.

Comment: Что значит "плоско"? В математике слово "неубывание" используется, например есть "неубывающие функции".

Answer (score 1):

Контекст дайте.
Без него мне неубывание/неубывающий вполне нравится.

Answer (score 1):

Неуменьшающийся, неснижающийся и другие синонимы к "неубывающий".  Неистощимый?